# Athena does not see new daily partion folders

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am working with Athena and have setup partitions for the Year/Month/Day.

I have performed one Glue crawl successfully, but all new dates do not show up. Is there a way to have Athena auto-detect new folders or is this just something that can only be done with scheduled Glue crawls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily handle this kind of dynamic partitioning using partition projection. See the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am new to the Athena/AWS Data Science space and it was really helpful to be able to know some more terms. I was really struggling with the words to look up more information about a problem that I didn't know about. 

For anyone else struggling and wanting a bit more in depth tutorial that specifically uses Glue. This tutorial talks about how to use Partition Projection with Glue 

https://raviintodia.medium.com/aws-glue-and-athena-using-partition-projection-to-perform-real-time-query-on-highly-partitioned-5aa06e90310d